# dW: IBM Datapower gatewayscript

Tags: ibm-datapower, ecma

I'm new to Datapower Gateway script. In my script I try to get value of context variable like var://context/WSM/identity/credentials.

I try something like:

```
session.input.getVariable('var://context/WSM/identity/credentials');
session.input.getVar('var://context/WSM/identity/credentials');
session.name('WSM');
```

But I alway have 'undefined' response.

My question how can I access from gatewayscript to a context variable ? And globaly, is these the right way to get user cr`enter code here`edentials or there is another way ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the session object:

```
var ctx = session.name('WSM') || session.createContext('WSM');
var value = ctx.getVar('identity');
```

Else you can use the service-metadata object:

```
var sm = require('service-metadata');
var value = sm.getVar('var://context/WSM/identity/credentials');
```

Comment: Hi Anders, IBM documentation say: Use the service-metadata module to access service variables not context variable !!

Comment: Hi Anders, I have processing error: incorrect service variable name

Comment: Try reading the full content of the var: session.ctx.readAsBuffer(function (error, buffer) {...});